# .NET Core Output formatters order

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 3 output formatters, one of which is my custom output formatter that should be triggered when SupportedMediaType is Excel (`Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel`).

```cs
      services.AddControllers(options =>
      {
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new ExcelOutputFormatter());; // Excel stylesheet XML
      }).AddNewtonsoftJson().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

However, if my header is `Accept: */*`, the application sends me to ExcelOutputFormatter. Is there a way for me to use the JSON output formatter instead of the Excel one by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to mimic the approach used by `AddNewtonsoftJson` and `AddXmlSerializerFormatters`, so that you can chain it *after* those two; this is relatively simple:

```cs
services.AddControllers(options => {})
    .AddNewtonsoftJson().AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddExcelOutputFormatter();
// ...
public static IMvcBuilder AddExcelOutputFormatter(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
        ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ExcelOutputFormatterSetup>());            
    return builder;
}
class ExcelOutputFormatterSetup : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    void IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>.Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new ExcelOutputFormatter());
    }
}
```

This should get the timing correct so that you're at the correct position in the chain.

As a side note: you may also want to add to `options.FormatterMappings`.

Answer (score 0):

Working off Marc's solution, you could minimise the code and make it more readable by using the `option.AddMvcOptions` method.

```
services.AddControllers()
   .AddNewtonsoftJson()
   .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
   .AddMvcOptions(options =>
   {
       options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
       options.OutputFormatters.Add(new ExcelOutputFormatter());
   });
```

This solved the issue for me.