# Asp.Net Core Keep default output formatter after adding custom

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I'm using Net 5.0.
I added custom Output formatter for ObjectResult.

```cs
var result = new ObjectResult(list)
{
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
};
result.Formatters.Add(new ExcelOutputFormatter());
return result;
```

But now it returns my custom output for every request, no matter what I write to Accept Header.

I would like to keep */* to returns what it would if I didn't add my custom output formatter.
In my case I would like that application/json is something like default and use my formatter only for *application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet*.

I found XmlSerializerOutputFormatter, that I was abble to add before my formatter, and that way it returned XML as default and my excel only with specified header. But I didn't find JSON formatter that would works. I'm using some default .net core formatter, I'm not adding any formatter in Startup.cs.

This my Output Formatter

```cs
public class ExcelOutputFormatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public ExcelOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(IEnumerable<Person>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(
        OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
        var serviceProvider = httpContext.RequestServices;

        var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ExcelOutputFormatter>>();

        var persons = context.Object as IEnumerable<Person>;

        var workbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
        workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");

        workbook.SaveAs(httpContext.Response.Body);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding some parsing in your `WriteResponseBodyAsync`? check the Accept Header in `context.HttpContext.Request.Headers` and doing different actions based on that?

Comment: I wanted to use formatter so I wouldn't need to check header myself in the first place. If I add multiple formatters, every is called only for it types and first added is used if it wasn't able to determine any match. But I would like that it would use some kind of global setting since other controllers are returning json without specifing anything.

Comment: If you add a Formatter, they get evaluated in order. If a `CanWriteType` matches, it will always be used. So you will have to always add the check yourself.

Comment: I cannot check Accept header in CanWriteType to return false. My formatter is called also if I write text/plain to Accept. Maybe is there a way that I can get list of formatters that is used by default for controllers and add it to my ObjectResult formatters list?

Comment: My issue is similar but a little different.  I added my custom formatter in services.AddControllers registration.  ```lang-c# services.AddControllers(options =>
 {
  options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
  options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvOutputFormatter());
 })``` I am finding that the Accept header is respected, everything working as expected.  However - if an Accept header is not provided the default is the custom formatter.  Would prefer the default to be application/json formatter

Answer (score 0):

you should add your formatter to your mvc options

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new ExcelOutputFormatter ());
    });
}
```

you can review it here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/net-5-custom-output-formatter-6651eadef8e1

Comment: I think that I tried something like that, but it then used only ExcelFormatter and never json. Will try again, and let know. I hope that I will find time to get back to this problem in project.

Comment: I implemented same you review it here https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/net-5-custom-output-formatter-6651eadef8e1

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain your output formatter at the appropriate location.

```
services.AddControllers(options => {})
    .AddNewtonsoftJson().AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddExcelOutputFormatter();
// ...
public static IMvcBuilder AddExcelOutputFormatter(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
        ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ExcelOutputFormatterSetup>());            
    return builder;
}
class ExcelOutputFormatterSetup : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    void IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>.Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new ExcelOutputFormatter());
    }
}
```

I faced the same issue and above answer worked for me to keep json as default formatter and custom formatter based on Accept header...original link posted below
credits: [Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299090/net-core-output-formatters-order)

Comment: Well, but this would force me to use NewtonsoftJson. I didn't want to add new package/formatter because I didn't have any problem with build in (part of .Net libraries? I don't know). And I didn't found any method that will add the default json formatter explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override CanWriteResult;

```
public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.Accept, out StringValues accepts) || !SupportedMediaTypes.Contains(accepts[0]))
            return false;

        return base.CanWriteResult(context);
    }
```

Comment: Looks good. I hope that I will get time to try it soon and remove workaround.