# Keeping Default Output Formatters even after adding custom OutputFormatters

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have added a couple of Output Formatters for CSV and Word Doc to my ASP.NET Core Web API. Since then all the requests from UI (having `Accept Header */*`) are hitting the Outputformatters code. I understand that defining custom formatters overwrote my default JSON formatters. How would we preserve the default behavior to support JSON/XML and still use custom formatters??

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CSVOutputFormatter());
            });

   public class CSVOutputFormatter : OutputFormatter
        {
            public string ContentType { get; }
            public PDRDModels ViewModel { get; set; }
    
            public CSVOutputFormatter()
            {
                ContentType = "text/csv";
                SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentType));
            }
    
            public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
            {
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                var filePath = string.Format("xyz{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                ViewModel = context.Object as model;
    
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {              

         /* Business Logic for populating csv */
                response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Pdrd.csv");
                response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    
                await response.SendFileAsync(filePath);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's removing the default ones?

Comment: The regular API calls which should return JSON are not working anymore...Every API call is going through the outputformatter

Comment: Well what is the content of `CSVOutputFormatter` then? Is it taking over all the mediatypes for example?

Comment: Edited the post with CSVFormatter code

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in the order the outputformatters are added. Thedefault are JSOn and XML formats. When adding custom formatters, we should make sure the custom formatters are added in the end of the outputformatters.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299090/net-core-output-formatters-order) post helped me figure out the issue and add the output formatters in the right order